# I can't fix size AVcapture with this code

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, avcapturesession

I need to fix screen capture on horizontal But this my code can't fix size screen capture follow code >   **previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(20, 40, 500, 100)**.
see on below this screen picture not match with **CGRectMake(20, 40, 500, 100)**.

[This is small size not match follow code(CGRectMake(20, 40, 500, 100))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0odgX.jpg)

please let my idea or example code for custom size this thank you.

This some code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

protocol BarcodeDelegate {
    func barcodeReaded(barcode: String)
}


class barcodeCapViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    var delegate: BarcodeDelegate?
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var code: String?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession();

        let videoCaptureDevice: AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        do {

            let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)

            if self.captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput) {
                self.captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
            } else {
                print("Could not add video input")
            }

            let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            if self.captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
                self.captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

                metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
                metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code]
            } else {
                print("Could not add metadata output")
            }

            let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
            previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(20, 40, 500, 100)
            self.view.layer .addSublayer(previewLayer)
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error while creating vide input device: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        for metadata in metadataObjects {
            let readableObject = metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            let code = readableObject.stringValue
            if !code.isEmpty {
                self.captureSession.stopRunning()
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                self.delegate?.barcodeReaded(code)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the preview layer frame in viewDidAppear or in viewWillLayoutSubview

Comment: I try this but got same result :(